# Blender Game Engine Car Crash

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to make a car crash simulator in the game engine but I just can not figure it out. I have tried soft body physics many times and it failed. I am trying to make something like BeamNG drive. I basically just want to be able to run my car into another object and have it randomly deform.

Comment: BeamNG's car crash system has been in development for *years* by a pretty large team. It is incredibly complicated and has been carefully refined over extensive testing and feedback. As caleb lee pointed out, the BGE is going to be phased out soon. It is an old engine running with honestly outdated systems - I'd be impressed if you could recreate the car crash deformations in the BGE at all, nevermind doing it so it doesn't crash your computer as well.

Answer (score 1):

" I basically just want to be able to run my car into another object and have it randomly deform." that is very easy to do . add collision  sensor(senses collisions) to your car and add edit object replace mesh actuator (deforms your car(you have to make independent deformed model of your car))
here is example on how to make random deformations
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l32qN6CwzXs

Comment: if you want it to be more realistic you will have to add python (to get speed of the object and then deform the object according to speed of the object)

Answer (score 0):

Blender's Game Engine itself is not the best. In fact, as far as we know, the Game Engine will be removed in the 2.8 update.

I recommend that you import your objects to Unity, which is also a great free software for making 2d or 3d games.

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download

Comment: While the points you've made are all legitimate, some people might have specific reasons for still using the BGE - and more importantly, you didn't answer OP's question by simply recommending a different platform.